# trying to send an email through contact form but it doesnt work

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I am trying send an email through my contact form, here is my php code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

    $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
    $ln = $_POST['lastname'];
    $name = $fn . ' ' . $ln;
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['comment'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $to = "iesteghlal@gmail.com";
    $header = "From: $email \r\n";

    $send_contact = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

    if($send_contact){
        echo "We've recived your contact information";
        echo "Your email has been sent. Stay in touch with us.";
        echo $name;
        echo $email;
        echo $message;
        echo $subject;
        echo $mailheader;
        echo $body;
        echo "</br><a href='index.html'> Go Back. </a>";
    }
    else {
        echo "something not working";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Something wrong.";
}
```

when I press send, it goes to the next page and it gives me "something not working" error. I am not quite sure what is going wrong here.

this is my contact form:

```
<form role="form" action="send.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 5px; background-color:#D7D1D1;">
                          <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" required="" autofocus="" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" required="" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <textarea style="resize:vertical;" class="form-control" placeholder="Message..." rows="6" id="comment" name="comment" required=""></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <input class="btn btn-success" value="Send" type="submit" id="submit" name="send">
                                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>-->
                            <input class="btn btn-danger" value="Clear" type="reset">
                                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>-->
                            <button style="float: right;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

what is going wrong?

Comment: What error msg are you getting when the form is submitted?

Comment: @AmitThakur no specific error, it just shows a blank page and nothing else. the email is also not sent.

Comment: Make sure your host has php send mail() support or use **$_REQUEST[]** insted of **$_POST[]** in you code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a live test server for this or are you using the likes of an offline server such as Apache? If you are using an offline server the email will not send unless you have setup utilities to do so.

This is not an answer, but due to a lack of 50 rep I cannot comment.

EDIT

Suggestion of an auto-redirect after the post has been sent, rather than a manual link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000)
    function Redirect() {
        location.href='contact.php'
    }
</script>
```

Something like this can work, by adding to your existing code.